# How do I fix this ValueError?

Tags: python, integer, valueerror

I am trying to get an average from a text file that uses a def function. I am trying to convert the list from the text file to int(). Instead of converting it gives me the error: " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5, 5, 6, 7' ". The "5, 5, 6, 7" is one that I made from the proper .txt file. Here is the code:

```
def getNumberList(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lyst = f.read().split('\n')
        numberList = [int(num) for num in lyst]
    return numberList

def getAverage(filename, func):
    numbers = func(filename)
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)

def main():
    filename = input("Input the file name: ")
    average = getAverage(filename, getNumberList)
    print(average)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your file has more than one number on each line.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, you cant' pass `'5, 5, 6, 7'` to `int()`, you will need to split that.

Comment: But your code expects it to be just one number.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting by line but you are not splitting by commas, so you are trying to convert `5,5,6,7` to an integer, which is impossible.  You need to also split by commas after you split by line, and then combine them into one list, if you want to average all the numbers in the file.  The following should work:

```
def getNumberList(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        numberList = [int(num) for num in line.split(',') for line in lines]
    return numberList
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to split each element with lyst using "," because right now it is trying to convert each line which has "1,2,3" as input.

So, change this and try.

```
def getNumberList(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lyst = []
        temp = f.read().strip().split('\n')
        for i in temp:
            lyst += i.strip().split(',')
        numberList = [int(num) for num in lyst]
    return numberList
```

Comment: Shouldn't the assignment to `numberList` be after the loop?

Comment: Yes. Formatting mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.